# router-outlet is not getting update after router .navigation used?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, angular2-routing

I'm creating a app in which i have a header and a sidebar, where in header i have a login and logout button showing on basis of user action,and in sidebar have some navigation like ['dashboard','heroes','form','message'].

but after user do the google login my header logout button is not getting update and the router-outlet too.

my app.component.html

```
    <mat-toolbar class="header-color">
  <div class="row header-width">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="search-input-button">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-box">
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="search-box-button">
          <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="viewLogout === true" class="col-md-2">
      <img class="img-circle" width="62" height="55" [src]="myPhotoUrl" (click)="infoModal()">
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="viewLogin === false" class="col-md-2">
      <button mat-button class="login-button" routerLink="/auth/login">{{login}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 side-menu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">
          <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
          <span style="padding-left:12px;">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <a routerLink="/heroes">
          <i class="fa fa-th-list"></i>
          <span style="padding-left:12px;">Heroes</span>
        </a>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <a routerLink="/basic-information">
          <i class="fa fa-forumbee"></i>
          <span style="padding-left:12px;">Form</span>
        </a>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <a routerLink="/todoFirebase">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
          <span style="padding-left:12px;">Messenger</span>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10 main-menu">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the app.component.ts i'm hidding sidebar and header on the basis of login and lout out
   app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../core/data.service';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { UserInfoModalComponent } from '../../modals/user-info-modal/user-info-modal.component';

@Component({
  moduleId: 'module.id',
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Initial C';
  login: string = 'Login';
  viewLogout: boolean;
  viewLogin: boolean;
  subscription;
  myPhotoUrl;
  fileNameDialogRef: MatDialogRef<UserInfoModalComponent>;
  navigationSubscription;
  constructor(private ss: DataService, private router: Router,
    private dialog: MatDialog, private renderer: Renderer2,
    private el: ElementRef) {
    let uid = sessionStorage.getItem('user_uid');
    if (uid !== null) {
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      this.viewLogin = true;
      this.viewLogout = true;
      this.myPhotoUrl = sessionStorage.getItem('user_photoUrl');
    } else {
      this.viewLogin = false;
      this.viewLogout = false;
    }

    this.navigationSubscription = this.router.events
      .subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          if (event.url.slice(1) === 'dashboard') {
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement.childNodes[0], 'hide-toolbar-sidebar');
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[0], 'hide-toolbar-sidebar');
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[1], 'do-the-center');
          } else if (event.url === '/auth/login' && uid === null) {
            this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement.childNodes[0], 'hide-toolbar-sidebar');
            this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[0], 'hide-toolbar-sidebar');
            this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[1], 'do-the-center');
          }
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ss.getEmittedValue().subscribe(item => {
      console.log("inside ngOnit method of app component=====" + item);
      this.viewLogin = item;
      this.viewLogout = item;
      if(item){
        this.myPhotoUrl = sessionStorage.getItem('user_photoUrl');
      } 
    });
  }

  infoModal() {
    this.fileNameDialogRef = this.dialog.open(UserInfoModalComponent, {
      hasBackdrop: true,
      height: '400px',
      width: '270px',
      position: { top: '10px', right: '100px' }
    });
  }

}

app.component.scss
.hide-toolbar-sidebar {
   display: none;
}
.do-the-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:100px; 
}
```

after user do the google authentication,in the success callback i m navigation to the /dashboard but the router-outlet and the header is not getting update from the login component

Here is my login.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseLoginService } from '../../core/firebase.login.service';
import { DataService } from '../../core/data.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  moduleId: 'module.id',
  selector: 'my-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.scss"]
})
export class LoginComponent {
  user = { username: '', password: '' };
  files: {};
  get myContent() { return JSON.stringify(this.user); }

  constructor(private firebase_login_service: FirebaseLoginService,
    private ss: DataService,
    private router: Router,
    private matDialog: MatDialog) { }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("my console from onSubmit" + this.user);
  }

  googleLogin() {
    console.log("i m inside google Login method");
    this.firebase_login_service.getAuth()
      .then(result => {
        //here is the browser gets update but the router-outlet is not getting updated.
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        sessionStorage.setItem('user_uid', result.user.uid);
        sessionStorage.setItem('user_photoUrl', result.user.photoURL);
        sessionStorage.setItem('user_emalid', result.user.email);
        this.ss.hide();
      });
  }



  cancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    this.matDialog.closeAll();
  }
}
```

I have deployed my app in firebase 
https://angular-project-5cb99.firebaseapp.com/dashboard

and the git repository : https://github.com/ashishsober/Master-detail-with-ANG2

please let me know the best approach to do this kind of functionality and provide me the solution as i have tried changeDetection and ngZone which also not required here.

please let me know for any clarification.

Comment: got the solution thank you

Comment: Put answer to your question then. Good work

Comment: create a child routes,so it will navigate to dashboard and other will be login view,

Comment: Yes so answer you question and mark it as answered.. I know the solution.. Thanks

Comment: Answer your question with the proper answer in the proper field

Comment: You can refer this repository https://github.com/ashishsober/Master-detail-with-ANG2

Answer (score -4):

Please for above solution ,You guys can refer this repository
[Respository link for above scenario](https://github.com/ashishsober/Master-detail-with-ANG2)

Comment: This is not considered an answer, you need to explain what you did to solve the issue, you cannot just paste a link to a repo. You also need to accept your own answer.